# How do I open new links in a JavaScript pop-up window (same window) not a new tab?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, hyperlink, popupwindow

I got an ASP.NET solution in which users can click on a hyperlink and have a small JavaScript modal/pop-up window opened. When I tried to open a new link within the pop up window, it would be opened in a new tab of the main window (not the modal window) which did not meet my client's requirements. Here is the hyperlink url property in my webform:

```
hyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "javascript:window.open('https:////www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1RLNS_enUS864US870&tbm=shop&q=dietary+supplement+for+diabetes&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfjNjg78XpAhXTu54KHckBC4kQBQiXAygA&biw=1680&bih=890', null, 'top = 100,left = 200,width = 1200,height = 800')";
```

I just want to ask if it is possible to have the window configured for new links to stay being opened within the same pop-up/modal window not the main window? Or this is something has to do with the browser preferences on opening a new link?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why dont You use Bootstrap 4 Model.

Comment: You've got two too many slashes in your URL. Should just be `'https://www.google.com/...`